# Killing a parent and killing a foster parent

Tags: philosophy, sutras, tipitaka, suttas

We all know what happens if someone kill a parent but does the same apply to killing a foster parent

Answer (score 3):

Killing a normal human being itself is a serious bad karma. So while killing a foster parent is not an Ananthariya Karma, it is still a severe bad karma depending on how good he/she was.

Answer (score 1):

If you intentionally kill your biological parent, you will commit ‘Anantarika karma’, which means you will not escape from it until you achieve Nirvana.

You will go to hell and suffer, then you may be born in a lower realm and suffer. After that, you may be born as a human or god according to your karma.

But you will face significant negative effects until you achieve Nirvana